Recover lost disk space (> 270 GB)
I have a brand new Mac with 4TB of SSD and it seems that ~270 GB are lost. I'd like to recover them if possible.
Below is the explanation on how I arrived to that total.
Disk Utility shows the following:

Used: 388.24 GB
Other Volumes: 17.88 GB
Free: 3.59 TB

Macintosh HD info shows:

Available: 3.59 TB
Used: 398.5 GB

There's a slight discrepancy of 7.62 GB between Disk Utility (total used 388.24 GB + 17.88 GB = 406.12 GB) and Macintosh HD info: 406.12 GB - 398.5 GB = 7.62 GB, but that's ok (Macintosh HD does not show other volumes sizes).
When I look at System Settings → General → About → Storage → Storage Settings..., the graphic shows: 402.11 GB used, which is more or less in line with Macintosh HD info.
Lower in the Storage window, I get:

Applications: 24.48 GB
Developer: 2.45 GB
Music Creation: 81.8 GB
Other Users & Shared: 261.1 GB
macOS: 18.34 GB
System Data: 13.94 GB

For a total of 402.11 GB which, thankfully, corresponds to the graphic part at the top of the window.
However, when I open a Finder window → Macintosh HD and request info on the existing folders (both visible† and hidden), I get the following:

.vol: 0 byte
Applications: 24.54 GB
bin: 4.9 MB
cores: 0 byte
Library: 87.49 GB
opt: 204.3 MB
private: 2.87 GB
sbin: 2 MB
System: 14.3 GB
Users: 1.06 GB
usr: 705.9 MB
Volumes: 1 byte

The total of both visible and hidden folders is 127.39 GB + ~3.79 GB respectively, for a grand total of ~131.18 GB.
The difference between what Storage indicates and what I can gather between the info of the individual folders is quite big: 402.11 GB - 131.18 GB = 270.93 GB
For information, Time Machine has not yet been set up on the computer, therefore the suggestion of this Ask Different thread won't work in this case.
My questions:

Any idea on how to find out where are those 270.93 GB gone and, crucially, how to recover them?
Would System Settings → General → Transfer or Reset → Erase All Content and Settings... solve the problem or just be a waste of time?


System used:

Apple M3 Max
128 GB RAM
macOS Sonoma 14.6.1

Other info:

Trash can has been emptied in all profiles
Computer has been rebooted several times


† Applications, Library, System, and Users are visible folders, the rest is hidden and can be rendered visible by pressing cmd-shift-., to hide them again press again the same combination keys.

In Finder - Macintosh HD info, how much is listed under "purgeable"?

Users: 1.06 GB sounds suspiciously low if even Library has gone beyond 50 GB. I'd open Terminal and run sudo du -s --si /Users. I would expect that to either print a number closer to your 270 GB than to 1 GB, or to print some errors about folders that you don't have access to.

I ended up by choosing the option Erase All Content and Settings. Even after reinstallation of all the apps as before (and more), the disk usage is still below 150GB (free space ≈ 3.85 TB), so nowhere near the ~400 GB of the first installation. This means that when I migrated the profiles from the old computer to the new one, some unknown data was transferred along. Will open another question in SA to ask if there's a way to transfer only specific data from one computer to the other…

This is likely completely expected and normal.
First, when dealing with disk storage space, there are a number of items that you have to take into account which are worth being aware of.
Overall Drive Space:
Your overall available drive space is going to be much lower than the 2TB (or other units advertised), for a variety of reasons, including:

Decimal vs binary storage units - because storage drives are advertised in decimal units, your 2TB hard drive actually only has about 1.73TB of storage space.
A portion of that drive space is reserved for the drive firmware
A portion of the drive storage is used for the partition maps and other storage overhead.
A portion of the drive is reserved for (Over-provisioning) - typically 7% to 28% of the drive. This allows the SSD to load balance the wear and provide backup as sectors become used or if they are marked bad.
Space reserved by the system for factory images, such as the Operating system restore partition (used if you reset your computer or rebuild from scratch). This partition is likely covered in your "Other Volumes: 17.88 GB" portion)

Usable Drive Space
Now that we're left the usable drive space, you're left with your usable drive space of 3.59 TB, which matches up in the "Available" in both, so there really isn't any discrepancy between the two in terms of total space available.
The difference you mention is expected, because what you are viewing are two different measurements.
When you select a folder and asking the Finder to tell you the size, it is manually counting up the file sizes for each file within the folder that it sees. Meanwhile, what you are viewing at the drive level, you're just looking at the drive's reported status space.
There will be a large discrepancy between those two, because the Finder "Get Info" doesn't' count all files - only those that are recognizable to Finder.  System files, snapshots, temporary files, etc are not always visible as files to the Finder.
In addition, there are also several files such as cache and journal files that are considered "purgeable", meaning the space is both used and free at the same time. (To the Finder, these files are free space, but to the drive, they are used. If you view the root entry of the drive, some of these will be listed in parenthesis next to "Available" as "purgeable)
If you are still concerned about your disk space and want to determine what is using it, I would recommend a tool such as DaisyDisk, Disk Inventory X, or GrandPerspective which should help you narrow down what space is being used where (and for what).

There's a lot of misinformation in this answer. Decimal vs binary isn't gonna have an impact because macOS switched to showing decimal a long time ago. If a drive has 4'000'000'000'000 bytes, macOS will show 4.0TB. Overprovisioning doesn't factor into this either, because that isn't even exposed to the OS. If you buy a 4TB drive, it has 4TB of usable space, regardless of how many it set aside for overprovisioning. The partition map is 4096 bytes on Apple's internal drives - about one billionth of the drive space in question, so absolutely negligible.

macOS itself (and that includes the drive firmware, recovery partition, etc.) might take up about 25GB, which is significant. But it should be noted that there is no "clean" image of the entire OS stashed anywhere. System recovery needs internet access if you want to restore the OS. But overall, if you sum up the OP's 388.24 GB, 17.88 GB and 3.59 TB, you get 3996.12 GB, which I would attribute to the 3.59 TB number likely having been rounded down to two digits.

These things would be so much easier if everyone switched to the ISO standard KiB/MiB/GiB/TiB… for the powers-of-1024 units, and used KB/MB/GB/TB… only for the powers-of-1000 ones.  (Many people/programs do, but not all, which is why there's still some ambiguity.)

FWIW, the open-source GrandPerspective has always worked well for me.

I agree that Decimal vs binary doesn't factor into his question, but they do factor into understanding the overall space, and are a very common misunderstanding, so I think they are very important to understand anytime a question about drive space comes up.

So you have

Other Users & Shared: 261.1 GB

all of which should be in the /Users directory while Finder reports 1.06GB for Users. I would look into that.
In a terminal, as an admin user, you can do
cd /Users
ls -al
sudo du -s --si *

and follow up on any large directories that you see there. Maybe there's old user directories / large files sitting around that you don't see from the current user profile.

Note that in general there can also be folders starting with . which wouldn't be taken into account by *, though this should not be the case in /Users.

This is a great comment. There could easily be files that are not visible to him that are owned by other users so the space isnt' showing up.
